# Is this just boilerplate code for a custom pager adapter implementation?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

In order for a `PagerAdapter` implementation to work properly the following should be implemented in the custom adapter derived class.

```
 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {  
        return view == object;  
 }  

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {  
        container.removeView((View) object);  
    }  
}
```

This seems to me just boilerplate code.
Why should that be done in the derived class? Is there a reason for this code not being part of the `PagerAdapter` and the derived class overrides it with something else only when (if) needed? When would that be?

Comment: I mean, just check the implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and you'll find your answer.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Why? I can use a `ViewPager` without any fragments.

Comment: Indeed. But FragmentPagerAdapter relies on ***not*** implementing these two methods the way you just did.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: They could have overidden them to achieve the same result right? So is that the only reason? To facilitate a specific derived class?

Comment: @Jim see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the Object isn't guaranteed to be a View. The documentation even says as much:

> instantiateItem
>
> Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not need to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.

If the `object` argument *isn't* a View, then `destroyItem()` will fail and cause your app to crash.

`isViewFromObject()` won't crash, but it'll always return false, which could cause a few hours of headache of trying to track the error.

Even if it is a View, and you're using PagerAdapter in its most basic form, I think the methods have been made abstract so that 1 you know about them, and 2 you're used to implementing them and know what to do if you aren't using a View as your Object.

Your View could have objects in it that need to be destroyed, like BroadcastReceivers, callbacks, etc. While it's not *required* to destroy these, it's good practice.

Comment: `Your View could have objects in it that need to be destroyed` yes but that is what an override could do anyway. Also I don't understand what container that is not a `View` it could be

Comment: Could be a Fragment. The View instance could be retrieved from `fragment.getView()`. If the Object isn't a View, the implementation you're suggesting be default will cause crashes.

Comment: You mean use `Fragment` and not `FragmentPagerAdapter`?